# Neo4j bolt driver protocol error

Tags: neo4j

I am getting below error while trying neo4j bolt driver to run simple cypher. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
    public void boltDriver() {
    Config noSSL = Config.build()
            .withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig();
    Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7474",
            AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j1"), noSSL); // <password>

    try (Session session = driver.session()) {

        StatementResult result;

        String foafQuery = " MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.country) RETURN DISTINCT \"node\" as element, n.country AS country ";
        result = session.run(foafQuery, parameters("name", "Joe"));
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            Record next = result.next();
            System.out.println(next.get("element"));
            System.out.println(next.get("country"));
        }

    }

}
```

Exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Protocol error, server suggested unexpected protocol version: 1213486160
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.negotiateProtocol(SocketClient.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.(SocketConnection.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.allocate(InternalConnectionPool.java:191)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.allocate(InternalConnectionPool.java:180)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.allocate(ThreadCachingPool.java:212)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquireFromGlobal(ThreadCachingPool.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquire(ThreadCachingPool.java:118)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool.acquire(InternalConnectionPool.java:109)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver.session(InternalDriver.java:53)
    at Neo4jMain.boldDriver(Neo4jMain.java:55)
    at Neo4jMain.main(Neo4jMain.java:30)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using the wrong port number. 7474 is by default used for http whereas 7687 is the default for binary bolt protocol.

Comment: Can we use the bolt driver for older versions of neo4j. Or else, it is specific to 3.0.

Comment: No bolt driver is only for 3.0 (and newer).

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Worked fine after changing the port.

Answer (score 1):

An important hint is that 1213486160 is "HTTP" as a 32-bit big-endian number.